# How to select multiple columns from different table name with different values in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables product and specs. In product table it has columns like PhoneMake and PhoneModel and ProducId whereas in specs there are columns like Os_name, Dapps, Os_ram, ProductId. My question is how to select multiple column values from all these. 
Like

```
select * 
  from product
where true 
  AND PhoneMake ='Motorola'
  AND PhoneMake ='Nokia '
  AND specs.Os_name ='on'
  AND specs.Os_name ='on'
  AND specs.Dapps ='on'
  AND specs.Os_ram =512 
  AND specs.Os_ram =1
```

What is the correct mysql query ?

Comment: Between the two answers provided below, a solution emerges!

Comment: Can you please clarify - do you wish `specs.Os_ram` to be **equal to** either `1` or `512`, or **between** `1` and `512`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn about joins:

```
select * from product join specs on <condition>
where PhoneMake in ('Motorola','Nokia') AND specs.Os_name ='on' AND specs.Dapps ='on'AND specs.Os_ram IN(512,1)
```

That is a simple join with to tables. `<conditon>` have to be change to the foreign key relation between `specs` and `product`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM product 
  INNER 
  JOIN specs 
    ON <condition>
 WHERE PhoneMake IN ('Motorola', 'Nokia ') 
   AND Os_name ='on' 
   AND Dapps ='on' 
   AND Os_ram IN (512, 1);
```

Comment: IN() is commonly used in this instance. Also, a CROSS JOIN is unlikely to be desirable here

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you for your feedback, I've edited my answer to include it.

Comment: :-) Now you're confused between a LEFT [OUTER] JOIN and an INNER JOIN. You have a LEFT JOIN that renders as an INNER JOIN (You can prove this by running EXPLAIN EXTENDED followed by SHOW WARNINGS). That said, the end result is probably right - because an INNER JOIN is probably what's required here! Finally, please look at formatting your queries more clearly and fully qualifiying your column names, just as the OP has done!